# How to change icon color individually for each option in <select>?

Tags: html, css

I tried to change just the icon color of a  but I couldn't, the most I changed was the color of the entire option (icon and label).

I want to change the color of the first icon to red and the second to green.

I try this:

```css
#fontaweinc1 {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'sans-serif';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id='fontaweinc1'>
            <!-- Alteração para tornar o primeiro ícone vermelho -->
            <option value="anchor" style="color: red;"><i class="fa">&#xf13d;</i> ANCHOR LABEL</option>

            <!-- Alteração para tornar o segundo ícone amarelo -->
            <option value="flask" style="color: green;"><i class="fa">&#xf0c3;</i> FLASK LABEL</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a fellow CSS developer myself, I'd love this feature to exist, however at this time this feature doesn't exist in browser because the select box is a native browser element and you can't style, on the other hand you could make your own dropdown box to allow you to add this feature but it adds a lot of complexity. [An example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) demonstrates how you could create your own dropdown box but you should also consider that it wouldn't be as accessibility friendly without aria rules.